# Acceder a los datos de otro componente en Angular

Tags: angular

tengo dos componentes, uno llamado product-items y otro product-list, en el product list, accedo a mi servicio y traigo todos los productos almacenados en la BD:

```
products: any;
  constructor(
    private productService: ProductsService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.products = res;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

Este es el html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let product of products">
    <app-product-item></app-product-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quiero que mi otro componente muestro los datos del producto, tenia algo así para hacer la prueba

```
<div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">

  {{ product.name }}
</div>
```

El ts

```
product: any;
  constructor(private products: ProductListComponent) {
    this.product = products.products;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.product = this.products.products;
  }
```

Pero igualmente a la hora de iniciar todo, me aparece en blanco el dato que trato de traer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te lo trae en blanco porque el `ProductListComponent` inyectado en el `ProductItemComponent` no es la misma instancia. *Angular* está creando otro objeto del tipo `ProductListComponent` para pasarlo por el constructor.

La forma de pasar datos de un componente a otro es una directiva [`@Input()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input).

```
@Component({...})
export class ProductItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product: any; // <-- Convendría ponerlo del tipo de tu producto, no any

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Y en el HTML, pasar el producto como *input* al componente.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let product of products">
    <app-product-item [product]="product"></app-product-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero que sirva.